# Is it possible to combine different type of Toolbar definition in Kendo Grid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

I have some old code that defines a toolbar in the grid like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Object>().Name("SomeGrid")
    .ToolBar(toolBar => toolBar.Custom()
        .Text("<i class='icon-download'></i> Exportieren")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "export" })
        .Url(Url.Action("Export", "ControllerName", new { page = 1, pageSize = "~", filter = "~", sort = "~", ElementId= ViewBag.CurrKompfGrp }))
    )
...
```

I'd like to add more buttons into it.
The best way I found and use so far in other grids is with .Template function:

```
        .ToolBar(toolbar =>
        {
            toolbar.Template("<a class='btn' id='panelAddAktionButton' onclick='aktionen.addItem();'><i class='icon-plus' rel='tooltip' title='add action'></i> </a> " +
                                "<a class='btn' id='panelEditAktionButton' onclick='aktionen.editItem();'><i class='icon-edit' rel='tooltip' title='Edit action'></i> </a> ");
        })
```

However, the problem is that I cannot see how I can easily convert one approach into another.
When I try to add several items into the approach number 1, the Visual studio underlines it as an error.
And as the url is dynamic in the first approach, it is problematic to transform it into the second one.

I also tried to combine two - but got error again.

Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone has the same problem. Kendo guys answered that the two approaches cannot be combined. If a toolbar template is added, it overrides all of the previous content. Nevertheless multiple custom commands could be defined, when the initial approach is used and an object is passed to the Toolbar Action Builder.

I had some more issues trying to use toolbar.Custom() with bootstrap buttons (an empty unnecessary element appeared near each button, but Kendo people said that this is not a bug). So I ended up doing this:

```
    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
    {
        toolbar.Template("<a class='btn' id='panelDownloadItemButtonPLZ' onclick=lokaleSperrlisten.downloadSperrliste('grid41897')><i class='icon-download' rel='tooltip' title='Download'></i> </a> " +
                         "<a class='btn ' href='" + Url.Action("ExportSperrlisten", "Vorbereitung", new { page = 1, pageSize = "~", filter = "~", sort = "~", sperrlistenType = "PLZ" }) + "' id='export1'><i class='icon-inbox'  rel='tooltip' title='Export'></i> </a>");
    })
```

Thus, the best approach was to convert everything to Template() structure.
Hope, this helps someone else.